# How to access and use Imported Function in ES6

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, export, es6-modules

I'm having trouble accessing the imported labelsForCountryCode function. When passing 'US' into this function, I'm expecting to have the US object returned. I'm new to ES6 and not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here. Appreciate any help!

**billing-address-labels-lookup.js**

```
export default function billingAddressLabelsLookup() {

const labelsLookup = {
  'US': {
    addressLineOne: 'Street/Address',
    city: 'City',
    provinceCode: 'State',
    postalCode: 'Zip Code'
  },
  'CA': {
    addressLineOne: 'Street/Address',
    city: 'City',
    provinceCode: 'Province',
    postalCode: 'Postal Code'
  }
};

return {
  labelsForCountryCode(countryCode) {
    return labelsLookup[countryCode];
  }
};
```

};

**test.js**

```
 import billingAddressLabelsLookup from '../utils/billing-address-labels-lookup.js';

 var labels = billingAddressLabelsLookup.labelsForCountryCode('US');
```

Comment: `billingAddressLabelsLookup` is a function, while you're trying to access to its result by passing the reference of it instead of calling it.. Just replace with this in **test.js**: `var labels = billingAddressLabelsLookup().labelsForCountryCode('US');`. Please check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace:

```
var labels = billingAddressLabelsLookup.labelsForCountryCode('US');
```

with:

```
var labels = billingAddressLabelsLookup().labelsForCountryCode('US');
                                       ^^------ function call
```

Otherwise, you're trying to access the **function reference's property**, while you need to access the **function's result**.

About import and exports, please take a look at this chapter specifically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export